# opening modal by passing Component of lazyLoaded module as template

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

**Problem**

i am using ngx-Bootstrap from valor-software
I want to open a modal by clicking a button in header component and pass NewEmailComponent that is located inside Email Module(LazyLoaded ) to its parameter as template

**Template**

```
<button (click)="openNewEmailInModal()">contact us </button>
```

**code in ts file**

```
openNewEmailInModal(){
    this.bsModalService.show(NewEmailComponent,{class:'modal-md'});
}
```

But I get The Error

**Error**

```
No component factory found for NewEmailComponent . Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

**current Set Up**

But I have already Added it to the entryComponents of EmailModule.

**Question?**

so how can I access entryComponents of Lazyloaded modules when I need it.

**What cant considered as solution**

obviously moving NewEmaiComponetent to App Module is not the solution , because the application is big enough and mature, so moving it to require much refactoring.

Comment: What structure does your project have? I mean, where do you import ModalModule, EmailModule etc?

Comment: they are both imported in app module which is the root module of my application

Comment: Could you create a reproduction? I tested it locally using latest version and it works fine. Starter templates for ngx-bootstrap project: Plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/0NipkZrnckZZROAcnjzB?p=preview

StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-bootstrap?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: the problem is Lazyloaded Module, they have their own injector and components defined in entryComponents are only available to the module not outside it. solutions you have provided is a single component and single module, if you have two module and one of them is lazy loaded then you will encounter error

Comment: Please create github repository with minimal reproduction.